# Symfony 4 modal form

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, doctrine, twig, symfony4

I have a list of cars, each car has a button, and pressing the button allows me to access a modal form to write a ticket for that specific car. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUnf0.jpg

The problem is that I'm having some problems integrating the modal and the form inside my twig.

The form I'm supposed to fill has 4 inputs alltogether. the first 2 are supposed to get pre-filled by data passed from the car related to the pressed button, the rest I can fill myself. But I don't know how to pass these informations from the twig to the form.

**What I did so far :**

- I have my list, my button in an index.html.twig file, and I have my form inside a model in a separate twig called modal.html.twig, I also made a controller.

**Problem :**
Pressing the button won't show anything.

**My code :**

index.html.twig

```
{% block title %}Parking index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}


  <table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      {% for voitures in voiture %}            
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ voitures.matricule }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voitures.parking.libelle }}         
            </td>
            <td>
             <span class="timer" data-expires="{{ voitures.getExpiresAt() }}"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" href="{{ path('new_ticket', {'id': voitures.id},{'parking': voitures.parking.id}) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createmodel" data-whatever="{{ voitures.id }}">ticket</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

My modal.html.twig form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                   <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="createModalLabel"><i class="ti-marker-alt m-r-10"></i> ticket for:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ form_start(form) }}

                        {{ form_row(form.Matricule, { 'label': 'Matricule' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.Parking, { 'label': 'Matricule' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.Date, { 'label': 'Date' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.montant, { 'label': 'Montant' }) }}

                        <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Add') }}</button>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}



                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="ti-save"></i> Save</button>
                   </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally my controller (which doesn't work)

```
    /**
     * @Route("/ticket", name="new_ticket", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function newTicket(Request $request): Response
    {
        $ticket = new Ticket();
        $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('success','ammende added !');

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($ticket);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('agent');
        }

        return $this->render('Agent/modal.html.twig', [
            'ticket' => $ticket,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

**This is the solution I found :**
I used render to integrate the form inside my index, it's not perfect but it works:

```
         {{render(controller('App\\Controller\\AgentController:newTask')) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.
The first error is that you have declared two forms one inside the other.
`{{ form_start(form) }}` prints `<form>` tag. The second problem is that you have not associated a form to a car. For example you should render a modal for every car and pass it the route where do you want post.

I leave here an example

```php
 {% for voitures in voiture %}            
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ voitures.matricule }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ voitures.parking.libelle }}         
            </td>
            <td>
             <span class="timer" data-expires="{{ voitures.getExpiresAt() }}"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createmodel" data-whatever="{{ voitures.id }}">ticket</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% set submit_url = path('new_ticket', {'id': voitures.id},{'parking': voitures.parking.id}) %}
          {% include 'modal_form.html.twig' wiht {url: submit_url} 
     {% endfor %}
```

And the modal it can be:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="createmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
           {{ form_start(form, {'action': url)}) }}
                   <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="createModalLabel"><i class="ti-marker-alt m-r-10"></i> ticket for:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                        {{ form_row(form.Matricule, { 'label': 'Matricule' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.Parking, { 'label': 'Matricule' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.Date, { 'label': 'Date' }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.montant, { 'label': 'Montant' }) }}
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                   </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="ti-save"></i> Save</button>
                   </div>
             {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error "Variable "form" does not exist." I think it has to do with the controller.

Comment: Sure, you pass to view the 'form' variable, you should do something like this `['form' => $form->createView()]` and you should render index.html.twig

Comment: ah I already did it, thanks a lot, I used                 {{render(controller('App\\Controller\\AgentController:newAmende')) }} inside my index

Comment: FYI: If you use Boostrap for Web Pack Encore, the tags are data-bs-toogle and data-bs-target